# Inline class with super class usage refactoring

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Suppose I have these classes:

```
class GoodClass
{
    //... stuff...
    public GoodClass(...) {...}
    //... stuff...
}

class BadClass extends GoodClass
{
    public BadClass(...) {super(...);}
}

class SomeOtherClass extends BadClass
{
    //... stuff...
}
```

I want to remove `BadClass` and use `GoodClass` everywhere.

Is there a way to do it easily with IntelliJ IDEA? So, it should literally replace all usages of BadClass with GoodClass: variable/field types should be changed, constructor calls should be replaced, inherited classes should change their parent, and everything else if I forgot something.

I've tried to use "inline class" but it doesn't do that I expect.

Comment: Have you simply tried Find all, Replace ( Ctrl + Shift + R ) > BadClass with GoodClass?, then delete the renamed BadClass, obviously

Comment: Probably not directly, since what you're doing isn't a full-blown refactor.  Can you guarantee that the uses between `BadClass` and `GoodClass` are compatible with each other?  That is to say, are whatever methods being invoked in `BadClass` going to return the same thing as `GoodClass`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Find/replace works, but not perfectly. E.g. if I have a field "BadClass badClass" I expect to have "GoodClass goodClass" after the refactoring (similar to a class rename refactoring) and so on.

Comment: @Makoto In my case - yes, BadClass doesn't have anything except constructors at the moment, I've pulled all members up.

Comment: @cricket_007 No, doesn't work for me as the classes are in different packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find/Replace will do 70% of the job. You might have to fix package names on your own later.

Another idea

1. Rename GoodClass to WantedClass;
2. Rename (on IDE) BadClass to GoodClass;
3. Close your IDE;
4. Go to src directory, remove GoodClass.java (old BadClass);
5. Now rename WantedClass.java to GoodClass.java
6. Open it and change the class name as well.

Comment: No need to close IDE though. Just used simple file delete, not "safe delete".
Also "structural search and replace" works, but sometimes crashes IDE...

Comment: Well noted. I said to close IDE because it will be safe on any IDE.